# Finding out if a motherboard supports UEFI

Tags: bios, uefi

I have read somewhere that computers prior to 2011 are unlikely to support UEFI. When I want to be certain if a computer supports UEFI then I goto the BIOS and check if there is a reference to the term UEFI over there.

The above is a bit hackish. My query is : Is there a way I can surely discover if a computer supports UEFI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can surely discover if a computer supports UEFI ?

There isn't and the question is ill-formed.

BIOS and UEFI are both firmwares for the same functions/purpose. UEFI replaced BIOS as a more modern and feature rich firmware. So, if you have one you don't have the other. Correctly speaking, one shouldn't call UEFI as BIOS or "BIOS of the UEFI type" or "UEFI supporting BIOS" as suggested by your question. It makes as much sense a "horse carriage supporting an engine. No, call it what it is, a "carriage" with an engine instead of horses is a (motor)car.

Unfortunately there are many people and manufacturers still referring to BIOS up to this day because reasons: It's hard to let go of [something in use for ~40 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Personal_Computer) and it may take another generation until the language finally catches on the *de facto* obsolete status of of the BIOS acronym. Knowing how languages evolve is the reason why I so often insist in not using BIOS and UEFI interchangeably, the change only comes from frequency of use in the community.

Now, back to your question, checking for references to the term UEFI - also EFI, Legacy/CSM, Secure Boot, etc. - isn't "hackish". The fact is there's really no way to tell one from the other unless one looks for details that are UEFI-only characteristics like the boot management and that can only be ascertained by opening the firmware settings. One can't tell from the outside whether it's BIOS or UEFI because there isn't (yet) an UEFI exclusive hardware technology/feature/characteristic, i.e., something that would indicate UEFI because it couldn't work or be present in the old BIOS.